# What's the fastest way to remove the first item from a list?

Tags: applescript

I read about some fast `list` operations using `as a reference`, as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCDBHIE).

What's the fastest way to remove the first item from a list (maybe using `as a reference` and `rest of list`)?

E.g.:

{3, 5, 6, 2, 8}

turns into

{5, 6, 2, 8}

Comment: Since you asked for the "fastest way", you may want to post your question at http://macscripter.net/viewforum.php?id=2, where a number of long-time experienced AppleScript gurus hang out.  The below answers may be correct, I don't know.  Just suggesting this to be sure.

Comment: @JMichaelTX Cool, thanks!

Comment: @wch1zpink, there is likely little difference for lists of such a small size.  It becomes a much different issue when the list is hundreds or thousands of items.  I have seen discussions where the method makes a very big difference in that case.  IAC, it never hurts to get  second opinion from the gurus at Macscripter.net.   Nothing for you to fear if your method is the fastest.

Comment: @JMichaelTX You Just mentioned some good points.  My bad

Answer (score 6):

This will delete the first item from a list

```
set theList to rest of {3, 5, 6, 2, 8}
```

Returns {5, 6, 2, 8}

---

Alternately, this will delete the last item from a list

```
set theList to reverse of rest of reverse of {3, 5, 6, 2, 8}
```

Returns {3, 5, 6, 2}

Answer (score 0):

```
--use my handler 

set b to {"A", 2, 3}

removeAnItemInList(1, b)
--result: {2, 3}



to removeAnItemInList(DeleteOffset, Listt)
    
    ---TH là 1 thì biến 1 thành {}
    if (count Listt) is 1 and (DeleteOffset is 1) then
        set Listt to {}
        return Listt
    end if
    
    --- TH  là 2 thì bỏ 1 hoặc 2
    if (count Listt) is 2 and (DeleteOffset is 1) then
        set Listt to item 2 of Listt as list
        return Listt
    end if
    
    if (count Listt) is 2 and (DeleteOffset is 2) then
        set Listt to item 1 of Listt as list
        return Listt
    end if
    
    ---TH >2 bỏ đầu cuối ----
    if (count Listt) > 2 and (DeleteOffset is 1) then
        set Listt to items 2 thru end of Listt
        return Listt
    end if
    
    if (count Listt) > 2 and (DeleteOffset is (count Listt)) then
        set Listt to items 1 thru -2 of Listt
        return Listt
    end if
    
    ---TH >2 bỏ giữa
    if (count Listt) > 2 then
        set Listt to items 1 thru (DeleteOffset - 1) of Listt & items (DeleteOffset + 1) thru end of Listt
        return Listt
    end if
    
end removeAnItemInList
```